# Pandas equivalent of vlookup for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to return the the total_points column for each user under multiple user columns.

To explain it clearer

```
{'secondBoxer1': {0: 'Cody',
  1: 'Billy',
  2: 'Jennifer',
  3: 'Franc',
  4: 'Mark'},
 'secondBoxer2': {0: 'Tamis',
  1: 'Danye',
  2: 'Leesa',
  3: 'Hector',
  4: 'Coy'},
 'secondBoxer3': {0: 'Davin',
  1: 'Delbert',
  2: 'Kanisca',
  3: 'Luis',
  4: 'nan'},
 'secondBoxer4': {0: 'Caro',
  1: 'John',
  2: 'nan',
  3: 'Jose',
  4: 'nan'},
 'secondBoxer5': {0: 'Caro',
  1: 'Ryan',
  2: 'nan',
  3: 'Jose',
  4: 'nan'},
 'secondBoxer6': {0: 'nan', 1: 'nan', 2: 'nan', 3: 'Luis', 4: 'nan'}}
```

I have five secondBoxer columns, for each boxer column I would like to merge the column with to the total points column from a different dataframe that corresponds to the name under the secondBoxer column

```
    name            total_points
0   Hector            50.000
1   John              48.000
2   Jose              30.000
3   Luis              31.875
4   Billy             27.500
```

The desired output in this instance would be

```
secondBoxer1  total_points1  secondBoxer2  total_points2  ....
  Cody                          Tamis
  Billy          27.500         Danye
  Jeniffer                      Leesa
  Franc                         Hector        50.000
  Mark                          Coy
```

I tried unsuccessfully to combine a for loop to iterate through all the columns (the actual dataset has over 50 secondBoxer cols) and merging with the second dataset to get the total_points.

```
listen = ['secondBoxer1','secondBoxer2','secondBoxer3','secondBoxer4','secondBoxer5','secondBoxer6']
for i in listen:
    df=df.merge(df2[['name','total_points']],left_on=i,right_on='name')
```

However this returns an empty dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC with `map` then `concat`

```
out1=out.apply(lambda x : x.map(dict(zip(df.name,df.total_points))))
out1.columns='total_points'+out1.columns.str.strip('secondBoxer')
out=pd.concat([out,out1],axis=1)
```

Here we need `argsort` to rearrange the number

```
out=out.iloc[:,out.columns.str.extract('(\d+)')[0].argsort()]

out
Out[151]: 
  secondBoxer1  total_points1  ... secondBoxer6  total_points6
0         Cody            NaN  ...          nan            NaN
1        Billy           27.5  ...          nan            NaN
2     Jennifer            NaN  ...          nan            NaN
3        Franc            NaN  ...         Luis         31.875
4         Mark            NaN  ...          nan            NaN
[5 rows x 12 columns]
```

Comment: sorry what is 'out' in this instance, is that the first dataframe?

Comment: @Emm out=pd.DataFrame(d), d is the dict you showed to us

Answer (score 1):

here is another way:

```
s=df2.set_index('name')['total_points']
final=df1.assign(**pd.DataFrame(np.where(df1.isin(s.index),df1.replace(s),np.nan)
                                ,columns=df1.columns.str[-1]).add_prefix('total_points'))
print(final[sorted(final.columns,key=lambda x: x[-1])])
```

---

```
  secondBoxer1 total_points1 secondBoxer2 total_points2 secondBoxer3  \
0         Cody           NaN        Tamis           NaN        Davin   
1        Billy          27.5        Danye           NaN      Delbert   
2     Jennifer           NaN        Leesa           NaN      Kanisca   
3        Franc           NaN       Hector            50         Luis   
4         Mark           NaN          Coy           NaN          nan   

  total_points3 secondBoxer4 total_points4 secondBoxer5 total_points5  \
0           NaN         Caro           NaN         Caro           NaN   
1           NaN         John            48         Ryan           NaN   
2           NaN          nan           NaN          nan           NaN   
3        31.875         Jose            30         Jose            30   
4           NaN          nan           NaN          nan           NaN   

  secondBoxer6 total_points6  
0          nan           NaN  
1          nan           NaN  
2          nan           NaN  
3         Luis        31.875  
4          nan           NaN
```

Comment: df1 is the dataframe from the dictionary, pd.Dataframe(dictionary) and df2 is the second dataframe in the question